# Command runs at ssh login, don't want it to

Tags: command-line, ssh

When I SSH into my ubuntu server, I get the normal system info splash thing, but then a command runs immediately after, and I can't seem to track it down.

```
Last login: Tue Jun 30 15:20:22 2015 from [removed]
][: command not found
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)`
```

I assume this was when I tried getting java installed correctly for use with Jira/Confluence.

I've tried backtracking through some old guides I was looking at but can't seem to find where I might have `][` accidentally entered somewhere. Ideas?

Comment: Whats the output of `grep '][' ~/.bash_profile ~/.bash_login ~/.profile 2>/dev/null` ?

Comment: No output at all

Comment: What about `grep '][' /etc/profile`

Comment: Originally, `grep: Invalid regular expression` so I figured I'd try `grep '\]\[' /etc/profile`, which gave `grep: /etc/.profile: No such file or directory`

Comment: Oops..totally my bad..please check `grep '\]\[' ~/.bash_profile ~/.bash_login ~/.profile 2>/dev/null` and also `grep '\]\[' /etc/profile`

Comment: the longer command returns nothing, the second one returns `grep: /etc/.profile: No such file or directory`

Comment: No..the command is `grep '\]\[' /etc/profile`, not `grep '\]\[' /etc/.profile` ..the directories are different..

Comment: derp >.< my bad. output is `][`. I removed the brackets from profile, but on login, still getting `Usage: java [-options] class [args...]`

Comment: did you logout and login again ?

Comment: Indeed. the `][` is gone, but still getting the java usage message.

Comment: do the same for `java`..`grep 'java' ~/.bash_profile ~/.bash_login ~/.profile ~/.bashrc /etc/profile 2>/dev/null`  ..i have included `~/.bashrc` too as it is sourced by `~/.profile` in Ubuntu..

Comment: return was `/etc/profile:JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun
/etc/profile:JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun
/etc/profile:JAVA_HOME= /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
/etc/profile:JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7/openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java` I removed the space on the third line, that fixed it. Jesus >.<

Comment: The space was between `/etc/profile:JAVA_HOME= /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/` and `java` ?

Comment: Negative. The space between `JAVA_HOME=` and `/usr/`

Comment: That means the variable declaration was wrong..anyway let me put an answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user configuration files that are read while initiating an interactive login shell like `ssh` are:

- The user configuration files `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, `~/.profile` (any one of them, searched in that order)
- The global configuration file `/etc/profile`

Now the mentioned issues must be in one of these files or in any other file sourced from these files. So we need to search these files and `~/.bashrc` needs to be included as in Ubuntu `~/.bashrc` is sourced from `~/.profile`.

In case of `][` we can do:

```
grep '\]\[' ~/.bash_profile ~/.bash_login ~/.profile ~/.bashrc /etc/profile 2>/dev/null
```

On the other hand in case of `java` we need:

```
grep 'java' ~/.bash_profile ~/.bash_login ~/.profile ~/.bashrc /etc/profile 2>/dev/null
```

After finding the problematic lines we need to fix those to make them correct (or remove them if not needed).